# Did almost 300k children get married in 2000–2018 in the USA?

Tags: united-states, children, marriage

The article [Child Marriage in the United States: Prevalence and Implications](https://www.jahonline.org/article/S1054-139X(21)00341-4/fulltext) from the Journal of Adolescent Health makes the following shocking claim right at the top:

> We found that some 297,033 children were married in the U.S. between 2000 and 2018: 232,474 based on marriage-certificate data plus 64,559 based on estimates (Table 1). A few children were as young as 10 years when they married, but of those for whom age information was available, nearly all—96%—were aged 16 or 17 years.

In a country with a population of 300 million and change, this suggests that over an 18-year period, approximately 1 person in 1000 *of the entire population* became an underage bride or groom.  (At a time when overall marriage rates are at an all-time low and declining, no less!)  And if 96% of these (about 223,000) were 16- or 17-year-olds, there are a lot fewer of them than there are of the entire population.

A bit of back-of-the-napkin math with census data suggests there were probably somewhere between 2-3 million 16- and 17-year-olds in the USA in 2018.  Divide that 223,000 by 18 and you have about 12,400 cases each year, or in other words, somewhere around 0.5% of all 16- and 17-year-olds in the country getting married every single year.  (Yes, this is very oversimplified math, but the figures should be in the right ballpark.)

That seems a bit excessive to say the least.  Is there any reason to believe these figures are anywhere near accurate?  If not, how did the researchers manage to come up with such wildly wrong figures?

Comment: A quick search says "Child marriage is currently legal in 41 [US] states". By that they mean under 18. So I'm not sure why you're shocked. Also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Child_marriage_in_the_United_States#Location

Comment: That article states that the "Unchained At Last" data was compiled from marriage certificate data for 38 states, which seems to me the most robust data possible. The remaining states are extrapolations, but that should not change anything fundamental here. I'm not sure what kind of data you expect here

Comment: To flip the context of your back of a napkin math: you're estimating that a town of twenty thousand people will have two hundred 16-17 year olds, two of whom will marry before their 18th birthday. Ignoring the emotive label of "child marriage", and accounting for cultural differences in attitude to marriage, that doesn't seem so surprising.

Comment: Their data looks really suspicious, especially the 76,396 children married in one particular year.

Comment: The quoted *"A few children were as young as 10 years when they married, but of those for whom age information was available..."* is quite odd. It suggests that the supposed 10 year olds had no age verification. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marriage_age_in_the_United_States#Underage_marriage) says *"5 states have no official minimum age, but still require either parental consent, court approval or both: California, Mississippi, New Mexico, Oklahoma, and Washington."* Only 10 states have a marriage age 18 the same as the voting age, so perhaps many could be called 'children'.

Comment: @IMSoP Having lived in a town that was slightly larger than that during the four years I was in high school and interacting with hundreds of kids that age on a daily basis... ZERO of them got married while still in high school.  If anyone had, it would have been all over the school rumor mill.  So yeah, the figures presented there feel an order of magnitude or three too high.

Comment: @MasonWheeler As I say, *accounting for cultural differences*, i.e. regional and social variation - don't mistake "average" for "normal", and don't mistake anecdote for data. It only takes one high school where four people married before leaving to balance your one school where none did.

Comment: Michigan gives exact data for their state: https://vitalstats.michigan.gov/osr/marriage/TabTeens.asp

Comment: Your napkin needs a little help. The birth cohort in the US is approximately 4 million per year. A small percent do not make it to age 16, close enough to say there are still 4M given that there is also immigration. And this is 16 and 17 year olds, so two years worth. (eg in 2018 there were 4 million people who had been born in 2001 and 4M who had been born in 2002).

Comment: Do these numbers include things like two 17 year old's getting married or others really close in age? Generally the age gap of the couple is important at that age but it doesn't seem to be factored in.

Comment: @MasonWheeler I went to high school in a town with 2,000 people.  2 students from my class got married (to eachother).  Does that mean the figures presented here are a magnitude or three too low?

Comment: @JoeW - there's definitely a difference in an 18-year-old and a 17-year-old getting married and, say, a 40-year-old and a 17-year-old

Comment: My wife has talked to me about how when she was growing up in the outskirts of Atlanta in the 90s, women/girls within the poorer part of her high school cohort (which was split between wealthy Black families and poor White families -- this was a place where the White people who were left were largely those who couldn't afford to move when the neighborhood's demographics changed) _very regularly did_ get married to much older men who had the financial standing to provide for them.

Comment: @Fizz  That something is legal in the US may often not mean that it isn't shocking :-) :-( . 
The majority of countries set minimum marriage age as 18. The US is an outlier. Legal marriages at 10 years old, reality in a few cases in the US, certainly should be shocking by almost all usual meanings of the term.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy what do you mean that the cohort was split between poor and rich families? this is the general situation in the US, no middle-class and a huge gap between who has and who has not.

Comment: @EarlGrey, it was less the case at the time (30-40 years ago) than it is now, but for the recency of the white-flight phenomenon in that particular area. (The Olympics have made Atlanta a very different place, demographically, than it was previously; this was before that transition).

Comment: @Fizz I think those remaining 9 states are Democrat.

Answer (score 36):

Firstly, let's take the emotive language out of the claim. The report takes the definition of "child marriage" to be a marriage involving any party under the age of 18 years old, and clarifies that:

> of those for whom age information was available, nearly all—96%—were aged 16 or 17 years

The headline figure also covers marriages conducted over a span of 19 years, and includes some uncertainty, between 200 thousand and 300 thousand married children.

On average, that's between 10 thousand and 16 thousand 16- and 17-year-olds marrying in the US each year. One of the tables in the report shows how that's declined over the period studied, from a lower-bound estimate of 76,396 in 2000 to only 2,493 in 2018.

---

The US Census Bureau published [a report in 2021 titled "Number, Timing, and Duration of Marriages and Divorces: 2016"](https://www.census.gov/library/publications/2021/demo/p70-167.html). It is based on the 2016 [American Community Survey (ACS)](https://www.census.gov/programs-surveys/acs/about.html) 1-year estimates, a weighted sample survey of about 3.5 million households.

Table 2 breaks down marital status by age groups, with the youngest group being "15-17 years". This age group is listed with a total population of 6,480,000 men plus 6,170,000 women, of whom 0.8% are classed as "ever married". Appendix C lists the corresponding margins of error as 14,690 plus 11,400 population and 0.1% "ever married".

That comes out at **88,367 to 114,084 people in the US population who were married before age 18**.

There's a few reasons why that number isn't directly comparable with the *Unchained at Last* estimate:

1. We don't know what year these people got married in. From the bare statistics, it's possible the marriages in question were spread over 17 years, giving as few as 3 thousand per year; but that would require as many 1-year-olds marrying as 17-year-olds. What we can say is that if the *Unchained at Last* numbers are true, *and* it's true that those numbers are mostly 16- and 17-year-olds, then the relevant years are 2015 and 2016, where they estimate at least 4,275 and 3,695 child spouses, respectively. So **the comparable *Unchained at Last* number would be around 8 thousand who were "ever married" in 2016**.
2. The survey would include anyone who married abroad, then moved or returned to the USA, as long as all of that happened before the age of 18.
3. The survey respondents may be including marriages which weren't conducted legally at all, but were recognised as such by their local community.

These factors may account for the ACS figure being significantly higher, but it suggests that the *Unchained at Last* figures are not wildly improbable. Unlike *Unchained at Last*, who are a campaign group, the Census Bureau has no motivation to exaggerate this particular figure.

Comment: IMSop, one source says that even though California only allowed less that 20 child marriages since 2019, California teens 15-17 keep telling the American Community Survey that 8000 per year were married https://calmatters.org/politics/2023/06/child-marriage-california/

Comment: "between 10 thousand and 16 thousand 16- and 17-year-olds marry in the US each year" isn't what their data is saying.  It is saying that less that 2500 such marriages occur annually now because there has been a 97% decrease in the child marriage rate over the the course of the study (from 76,396 in 2000 to only 2,493 in 2018).

Comment: "includes some uncertainty, between 200 thousand and 300 thousand marriages.",  married persons, right? A single marriage could involve two underage persons, so the number of marriages is likely lower than the number underaged involved.

Comment: @ilkkachu Good catch, fixed.

Comment: @DavePhD I've fixed the mention of averages, good spot. If anything, it amplifies my point, which is that the study in the OP gives significantly *lower* estimates than the ACS, despite having every motivation to inflate them. If there's some point from the CalMatters article you think still isn't covered, let me know.

Answer (score 5):

> A bit of back-of-the-napkin math with census data suggests there were probably somewhere between 2-3 million 16- and 17-year-olds

[Really](https://www.abi.org/newsroom/chart-of-the-day/us-population-by-age?gclid=EAIaIQobChMI0YvP07yIggMVwvPICh0ExwkyEAAYASAAEgLAk_D_BwE) there are over 8.5 million who are/were 16 or 17

> That seems a bit excessive to say the least. Is there any reason to believe these figures are anywhere near accurate? If not, how did the researchers manage to come up with such wildly wrong figures?

They aren't that wildly wrong, but the statement that there were 76,396 children married in the year 2000 seems suspect.  [The US Public Broadcasting Service](http://apps.frontline.org/child-marriage-by-the-numbers/) says 23,582 were married in the year 2000.

Comment: The words "another source" aren't a great description to judge the reputation of a source. Who is the source behind that link, and why are they worth listening to?

Comment: Also note this "other source" has a large pull quote that says "Between 2000 and 2015, at least

207,459
minors were married in the United States".

Comment: @Fizz that’s what I mean by not wildly wrong.  Just that one year (2000) seems disputed by about 52,000.

Comment: @IMSoP I clarified that the source is the US Public Broadcasting Service.  But the data is not sourced total independent of the OP data.  The 4th reference of the OP article is the PBS source.  Mainly, the OP article should have explained how they radically increased the count for the year 2000 from 23,582 to 76,396 .  Basically they are saying 2% of all 16 and 17 year old girls got married in the year 2000.

Comment: The reference to PBS in the OP is not as a source, it's as background of previous research on the same topic. They are claiming - rightly or wrongly - that their new study is higher quality than their own previous effort and the additions to it by PBS.

Comment: @IMSoP I agree, but they should explain such a huge change in that one particular year